# EF 6 SaveChangesAsync() running slow

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have the following method:

```
    public async Task<int> AddCallDetail(List<CallDetail> addCallDetail)
    {
        int added = 0;
        using (InContactEntities context = new InContactEntities())
        {
            DateTime minDateTime = (from c in addCallDetail select c.StartDateTime).Min();
            DateTime maxDateTime = (from c in addCallDetail select c.EndDateTime).Max();

            var l = from d in addCallDetail
                    join c in context.CallDetails.Where(cc => cc.StartDate >= minDateTime && cc.StartDate <= maxDateTime)
                    on d.MasterContactID equals c.MasterContactID into dc
                    from c in dc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { cOne = d, cTwo = c == null ? null : c };

            List<CallDetail> callDetail = (from d in l where d.cTwo == null select d.cOne).ToList();

            if (callDetail != null && callDetail.Count != 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    context.CallDetails.AddRange(callDetail);
                    added = await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
                    added = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        return added;
    }
```

This will add call information from our phone systems api into the database I built. This will handle a maximum of 50,000 records at a time but on average it will handle 10,000 - 15,000 records. The linq expressions will run in 2 seconds consistently regardless of amount of records but the line `added = await context.SaveChangesAsync()` takes an extremely long time to process. By long time I mean roughly 20 min to add 11K rows. Now the call is async and awaited, lessening some impact, but I would still like to get the records inserted faster if possible. Any suggestions?

The table that it is inserting to does have two foreign keys, both of which are checked to ensure that the records are present before inserting.

Comment: u should consider bulk insert instead of save changes. see EF bulk insert extension.

Comment: You might also want to configure your context. Turn of validation on save and autodetect changes will make large inserts alot faster. Dont do updates though, then you'll have to tell your context to detect changes again. These settings can be changed in the context.configuration